# How to split text and put into the array based on my consonant array?

Tags: c#, arrays

This is my array:

```
{
   string[] consonants = new string[9];

        consonants[0] = "ඌ";
        consonants[1] = "උ";
        consonants[2] = "මෟ";
        consonants[3] = "මෑ";
        consonants[4] = "මැ";
        consonants[5] = "මූ";
        consonants[6] = "මු";
        consonants[7] = "මෛ";
        consonants[8] = "මේ";

        string line = textBox1.Text.ToString();
        line = line.Replace('\t', ' ');
        line = line.Replace('\n', ' ');
        line = line.Replace('\r', ' ');
}
```

I want to split text based on this array, as a example: if the text box has "මෑ" text I want match that with array  and that word it matched with array then it put into another array that text as it is.

Comment: Please show an example of the output you expect.  It's not clear to me what you want the function to do.

Comment: So you want to find every instance of the words in the `consonants` array and put them into a different array?

Comment: yes I want split my text box text based on this array text. I want to split text box text based on this consonant array index text please help me

Comment: Just use `var parts = line.Split(consonants,StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: but, it pass null value for parts I want to that string value not null value how can I handle this please help me?

Comment: Do not use comments to nag people into answering your question. This is rude. Please have a little patience and wait for people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just quick code

```
List<string> parts = new List<string>();
foreach(string separator in consonants)
{
    parts.Add(line.Split(separator));
}
parts = parts.Distinct().ToList();
```

I wrote it here quickly. It is possible that there is error it it. Check it.

parts is collection that will hold your separated parts.
at the end we remove all duplicated from the parts list.

BTW.
For consonats you should use "char" if you want to use one letter strings.

Comment: thanx. I try it. but it has an error. it say parts.Add(line.Split(separator)); is can't converted into char into string how can i fix this please help.

Comment: I want to build sinhala narrator so, I want to read all the text So that why I do this.

Comment: var parts = line.Split(consonants,StringSplitOptions.None); this work but it pass null value for parts matching value is null I want to matching string value. please help me........

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you need it. Try the code the other guy provided. Only add reference:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

and instead of:

```
parts.Add(line.Split(separator));
```

use:

```
parts.Add(Regex.Split(line,separator));
```

Comment: thax it also say, this error msg one argument can't converted in to string[] into string so please help me to fix it. please help

Comment: var parts = line.Split(consonants,StringSplitOptions.None); this work but it pass null value for parts matching value is null I want to matching string value. please help me........